# Regex needed in Java

Tags: java, regex

I have a line item called

PAYMENT - THANK YOU-$50.00.

I want to split this value as

PAYMENT - THANK YOU as key

and value as

-$50.00.

I wrote regex as follows

```
Pattern.compile("([a-zA-Z \\-? a-zA-Z]+)(-?\\$[0-9|,]*\\.[0-9][0-9])");
```

but I'm getting the key as PAYMENT - THANK YOU- and value as $50.00
could any one please help me what is the wrong in the regex

Comment: Explain better what you are doing.  If your line is always the same, just split at the known index.

Comment: The reason you are matching the `-` in `YOU-` is the same reason why you are matching the `-` between `PAYMENT - THANK` which is because you have said to match `-` in the first character set.

Comment: the description varies alwyas but it will be delimeted by -

Comment: So substring with [lastindexof](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#lastIndexOf%28int%29)(-)

Comment: Is there any reason you're not simply splitting on "PAYMENT - THANK YOU". And skipping reg-ex altogether?

Answer (score 7):

The reason why you're getting that is because the first block has a greedy regex.  The first group captures the `-` simply because it's allowed to.

one thing that will fix it is to remove the `?` after the `-`, forcing the `-` to be in the second regex

```
Pattern.compile("([a-zA-Z \\-? a-zA-Z]+)(-\\$[0-9|,]*\\.[0-9][0-9])");
```

http://rubular.com/r/MDHPux502R

---

considering the fact that the `?` was present in the first place, I suspect that the `-` is optional,

to make the first group non-greedy you can add a `?` after the `+`

```
Pattern.compile("([a-zA-Z \\-? a-zA-Z]+)(-?\\$[0-9|,]*\\.[0-9][0-9])");
```

http://rubular.com/r/In9M650QcB

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you're trying to accomplish with the `\\-?` part in your pattern, but this should work:

```
Pattern.compile("([a-zA-Z -]*[a-zA-Z ])(-?\\$[0-9|,]*\\.[0-9][0-9])");
```

Answer (score 0):

Unless otherwise specified, the data tends to go in earlier fields, where possible.

What you need to do is specify that the last character of the first field may NOT be a dash:

```
Pattern.compile("([a-zA-Z -? a-zA-Z]+[^-])(-?\\$[0-9|,]*\\.[0-9][0-9])");
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
"([a-zA-Z -]+)(-?\\$[0-9|,]*\\.[0-9][0-9])"
```

Your regex is catching the - in the first character group.

Answer (score 0):

Try the next:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("([\\S ]*[^-])(-?\\$[\\d,]*\\.\\d{2}).*");

    String line = "PAYMENT - THANK YOU-$50.00.";

    Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(line);
    String key = matcher.replaceAll("$1");
    String value = matcher.replaceAll("$2");

    System.out.println(key);
    System.out.println(value);
}
```

Output:

```
PAYMENT - THANK YOU
-$50.00
```

And:

[image]